# Firebase Database rules - Give unauthenticated user access to ONLY read specific path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules

Say my Firebase Database rules look like this:

```
"rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
  }
```

In my app I need to check if a username is already taken, and thus I need to do so before authenticating the user. I am aware that I could do something like this:

```
"rules": {
".write": "auth != null",
"Users": {
  ".read": true
}
}
```

However, if I have understood how the rules work correctly, this will make only the "Users" path readable and by default every other path will be set to `".read": false`. My question is therefore how I would make every path readable by an authenticated user, and make an unauthenticated user only able to read data from the path "Users" and nothing else.

Comment: By every other path, do you mean every other path inside "Users" such as `/Users/user1/name`? Or do you mean any other path that does not contain "Users"?

Comment: Why are you doing this? There's no reason to check if a username is taken - Firebase authentication handles logins for you and won't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you can make it so one path in the database is readable for unauthenticated users, but I wouldn't recommend it. It's not ideal to allow anyone to read the usernames of all of your users.

One other option is you can create a user first and then have them choose a username once authenticated, but then you'd have to figure out how you wanted to handle users who are authenticated but then exit the app before choosing a username.

A better option is to use Cloud Functions for Firebase with an HTTP trigger, and pass the desired username as part of the request. The request would include a query of the desired username and the response would return whether the username is available or not. It could look something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.uniqueUsername = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const username = req.query.username
    admin.database().ref('users').orderByChild('username').equalTo(username)once('value').then(snap => {
        // if the child exists, then the username is taken
        if (snap.exists()) {
            res.send('username not available');
        } else {
            res.send('username available');
        }
    })   
}
```

If you're new to Cloud Functions for Firebase, then check out these resources:

[Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase - YouTube](https://youtu.be/EvV9Vk9iOCQ?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM)

[Cloud Functions for Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

[Cloud Functions Samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)

[Timing Cloud Functions for Firebase using an HTTP Trigger and Cron - YouTube](https://youtu.be/CbE2PzvAMxA)

Comment: Sounds great! I will go read about Cloud Functions then, thanks a lot!